# segue.destinationVC is nil in prepareForSegue

Tags: ios, swift

I've looked around many threads and haven't benefitted with my issue. My issue lies in my 3rd VC where the user taps an 'Edit UIBarButtonItem' which segues them to the 4th VC. The segue ID is correct and both VC's 3 and 4 are static table VC's, but 4 is embedded in a nav controller and 3 isn't. i want the data in the textfields in VC 3 to be 'copied' to the almost identical looking textfields in VC 4, so that changes can be made by the user and updated. When i type cast my destination segue as the 4th VC inside prepareForSegue, it returns nil and the instance of data inside doesn't get moved to the 4th VC since 'if let' is being used. Why does it return nil? I've looked up the life cycle of segues too but haven't learnt much, all other VC's are fine.

I have tried both below and both return nil for VC 4

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "EditSegue" {
        print("correct segue name")
        if let editVC: EditTableViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? EditTableViewController {
            editVC.instanceOfData = self.instanceOfData //instance of data in 4th VC = instanceOfData in 3rd VC
        }
    }
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let editVC = segue.destinationViewController as? EditTableViewController
    if segue.identifier == "EditSegue" {
        editVC.instanceOfData = self.instanceOfData
    }
}
```

I could be doing something obviously wrong which i haven't come across yet! I've successfully transferred data between two VC's before but not when instances have been passed around between VC's.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Is the `segue.destinationViewController` an `EditTableViewController` or a `UINavigationController`?

Comment: is there a way i could check? in the storyboard the segue points to the nav controller